# Uno Platform RemoteControl - The Uno.WinUI.RemoteControl or Uno.UI.RemoteControl package has not been restored yet

Tags: visual-studio-2022, webassembly, uno-platform

I have been struggling to get the RemoteControl to consistently work for my WebAssembly head. I created the project using the built-in Uno project wizard. I am running on the following platforms:

- Windows 10 21H2 dev machine (19044.2728)
- Visual Studio 2022 Professional (17.5.5)
- Uno.WinUI.WebAssembly (4.8.33)
- Uno.WinUI.RemoteControl (4.8.33)
- Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap (7.0.20)
- Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap.DevServer (7.0.20)

I frequently (but not 100% of the time) get this error in the Uno Platform output window:

`[INFO] The Uno.WinUI.RemoteControl or Uno.UI.RemoteControl package has not been restored yet, retrying...`

I've tried the following with no consistent results of success:

- Restarting Visual Studio
- Closing the solution and re-opening
- Unloading the project and re-loading
- Restoring nuget packages for the solution (i.e. right-click solution and select "Restore NuGet Packages")
- Opening a vanilla, new solution with a new, blank Uno app in it, then switching back to my solution (this one works ~20% of the time)
- Increasing filesystem permissions on my packages folder for all users on the machine

Is there some additional logging for Uno/Uno.WinUI.RemoteControl I can view? I don't even know where to start troubleshooting, so any pointers are welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created an issue for tracking of this problem [here on GitHub](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/issues/12366). We will investigate this and respond there with latest updates.

Comment: to follow-up in case the link ever dies, there appears to have been a bug in the Uno Platform extension that was addressed, and new version of the extension with the fix was published. Thanks, @Martin Zikmund, for the assist on getting the issue opened in the right place.